# When will apple deprecate old method of IAP validation?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to find the dates when apple will no longer accept the old style IAP receipt validation previous to iOS7 ? I looked at the apple doc's but I could not find it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not about code, try asking in the [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) community on Stack Exchange

Comment: that is pretty much based on assumption, but I can tell you that will happen __in this millennium__.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "when will the `transactionReceipt` property disappear from `SKPaymentTransaction`"? That's happened in the Swift SDK.

Or do you mean "when will iOS 6 style receipts stop being accepted by Apple's web services?" That is unlikely to ever happen without a compelling reason to disrupt functioning code and purchase histories, so I wouldn't be overly concerned about that possibility. But [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) would be a good place to go visit and upgrade to current best practices. Just in case.